# How to expose object in node module

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, require

I've a module which is using parsing ( a parsing functionality), other modules should query this parser values.
my question is

1. how should I build it (design aspects ) ?
2. which method should init the parser (the first method that call it
   to get specific value)

This is sample code which return two object from the parser but I dont think that this is the right way to do that since maybe I'll need to provide additional properties

the is the module parse

```
 parse = function (data) {
        var ymlObj = ymlParser.parse(data);
        return {
            web: ymlObj.process_types.web,
            con: ymlObj.con    

        }

};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you right you can just make simple module with getters and setter.

(parse.js)

```
var ymlObj = {};

function Parse() {}

Parse.prototype.setData = function (data) {
    ymlObj = data;
}

Parse.prototype.getWeb = function () {
    return ymlObj.process_types.web;
}

Parse.prototype.getCon = function () {
    return ymlObj.con;
}

module.exports = new Parse();
```

(parseUser.js)

```
var parse = require('./parse.js');

function ParseUser() { }

ParseUser.prototype.useParse = function () {
    console.log(parse.getCon());
}

module.exports = new ParseUser();
```

(app.js)

```
var parse = require('./parse.js');
var parseUser = require('parseUser.js');

parse.setData({ ... });
parseUser.useParse();
```

You still have to do basics like handle exceptions but hope this helps you understand the basic structure.

What comes to init it really depends when you want to initialize (fetch?) your data and where does that data come from. You can set timestamp to indicate how old your data is and make decision if you still rely on it or fetch newer data. Or you can register callbacks from your user modules to deal with new data every time its fetched.

So its up to you how you design your module. ;)

Comment: Thanks 1+ One question why you use the prototype can you please explain?

Comment: Thats because in javascript every declared (new) object inherits from its prototype. To understand better read this: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_prototypes.asp